# Как получить текст из файла в сети интернет?

Tags: vbscript

Возможно ли на VBScript получить текст с веб страницы или из txt файла в сети? Если не сложно, то приведите код, пожалуйста. (сам файл VBS на запускается на компьютере)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить данные от HTTP сервера туда нужно отправить GET запрос. Это можно сделать множеством способов, например так:

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
o.send
```

Теперь внутри o.responseText содержится ответ сервера имеющий тип данных String. Делайте с ним что хотите(парсите, сохраняйте как файл, перепосылайте в другое место). Православная документация  по MSXML2.XMLHTTP находится [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923283.aspx)

Comment: Простите, а что является ответом от сервера?(там весь файл или что-то другое)

Comment: Исправил немного. o.responseText - ответ сервера.

Comment: А почему эта процедура не хочет повторяться несколько раз в цикле?

Comment: Dim o
Dim x
Dim b

Do
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://.../message.txt", False
o.send
b = o.responseText
If x <> b Then
MsgBox(o.responseText)
x = b
End If
WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
WScript.Quit